# using sqlitedatabase variable from another class in android

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a MunchaDbAdapter that opens the connection and initializes SQLiteDatabase to getWritableDatabase as below:

```
public MunchaDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new MunchDbHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

now in another class i opened the MunchaDbAdapter like this

```
private MunchaDbAdapter mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

public long insert(Recipient recipient, String[] images){
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(FLD_RECIPIENT_ID, Recipient.getFldRecipientId());
        initialValues.put(FLD_INFO, Recipient.getFldInfo());
        initialValues.put(FLD_LATITUDE, Recipient.getFldLatitude());
        initialValues.put(FLD_LONGITUDE, Recipient.getFldLongitude());
        for(int i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            if(images[i]!=null){
                initialValues.put("FLD_IMAGE_URL"+(i+1), images[i]);
            }
        }

        mDbHelper.open();
        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
```

here is my error the mDb is null so what is the problem could any body mention it?

Comment: you will need `mDb` instance for inserting data in database

Answer (score 0):

All I can get from the code is that you're trying to do this:

Class 1:

```
public SQLiteDatabase open() throws SQLException {
    MunchDbHelper mDbHelper = new MunchDbHelper(mCtx);
    SQLiteDatabase mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return mDb;
}
```

Class 2:

```
private MunchaDbAdapter mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

public long insert(Recipient recipient, String[] images){
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(FLD_RECIPIENT_ID, Recipient.getFldRecipientId());
        initialValues.put(FLD_INFO, Recipient.getFldInfo());
        initialValues.put(FLD_LATITUDE, Recipient.getFldLatitude());
        initialValues.put(FLD_LONGITUDE, Recipient.getFldLongitude());
        for(int i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            if(images[i]!=null){
                initialValues.put("FLD_IMAGE_URL"+(i+1), images[i]);
            }
        }
        mDbHelper = new MunchDbHelper(getApplicationCOntext());
        mDb = mDbHelper.open();
        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
```

Ofcourse, if you'd elaborate on the code you have I could help you better.